# Is KDE Qt licensing issue info misleading or Qt.io is wrong?

Tags: c++, qt

So in [qtissue](https://www.kde.org/community/history/qtissue.php) we see:

> If you want to sell your applications that you wrote using Qt and do
>   not wish to make your source code available for anyone to download,
>   then you need to buy a license from Troll Tech.

While in [Qt.io](http://www.qt.io/faq/) we see another picture:

> The LGPL allows you to keep the source code of your application
>   private as long as it is “work that uses” the library. Dynamic linking
>   is usually recommended here.

So this means now we can have a closed source application that uses Qt in form of .dll/.so shared libraries, we can distribute our application with that dll/so files, and sell it for money (on any platform where one may use Dynamic linking oof Qt)?

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago, Qt was licensed with GPL or a commercial license and this is reflected in the kde info.

Then I think Trolltech or Nokia added LGPL to the list, and this is reflected in the Qt.io info.